# Laravel Eloquent Model inserts all values as NULL

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have run into problems with Laravel Eloquent Model

I have a model as follow:

```
class Activity extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'activity';

    protected $timestamps = false;

    public $item;

    public $content;

    public $year;

    protected $fillable = array('item', 'content', 'year');
}
```

And the corresponding controller:

```
class ActivityController extends \BaseController {
     public function create()
     {
         $activity = new Activity();

         $actitity->item = 'Example';
         $activity->content = 'Example content';
         $activity->year = 2015;

         $activity->save();
     }
}
```

The above code should work fine and there should be a record in 'activity' table. However, all the value of columns of activity table are inserted as NULL when I run this code (except for the id column which is auto_increment).

In addition, when I var_dump the $activity (just before calling $activity->save()), the $activity with all of its properties are shown as expected (I mean, with values I've assigned before)

Is there any subtle error in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not define database fields as actual class properties. The problem is that Laravel uses an `$attributes` array internally, not the models properties.

When doing

```
$activity->content = 'Example content';
```

Laravel uses the magic `__set()` method to update the value in it's `$attributes` array. But that setter method is never called because you have an actual property with that name.

What you need to do to resolve this problem is remove the properties:

```
class Activity extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'activity';

    protected $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = array('item', 'content', 'year');
}
```

If you want to document the properties and have autocomplete support you can use the `@property` annotation:

```
/**
 * @property string $item
 * @property string $content
 * @property int $year
 */
class Activity extends Eloquent {
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I did not know about the __set() method. It's like a charm

Answer (score 0):

This is because Eloquent uses magic setters/getters. If you did `$model->randomAttribute` then it would look into the models attributes array for the data.

Because you have explicitly defined each attribute it directly accesses the property and not the magic getter. When you call `save()`, the function saves all the data in the attributes array which contains nothing.

Remove the attribute definitions and it will work.

If you call `$model->getAttributes()` you will see there will be no data contained within.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
public $item;

public $content;

public $year;
```

from:

```
class Activity extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'activity';

    protected $timestamps = false;

    public $item;

    public $content;

    public $year;

    protected $fillable = array('item', 'content', 'year');
}
```